# Is this validity check vulnerable?

Tags: php, code-injection, security

I have this code in a page that includes other files via GET request:

```
$page = strtolower($_GET['page']);

if(!$page or !$allow[$page] or $page == 'home') {
    header("Location: home.php");
}
```

where `$allow` is a hardcoded array which contains a list of the allowed strings that are valid files to be included.  Am I missing something obvious which would allow some code injection or is this check good enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not vulnerable as long as [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) doesn't allow $allow to be overwritten.

It will throw notices though, and personally I wouldn't have the case-insensitivity, so I'd do it like this:

```
if (empty($_GET['page']) || empty($allow[$_GET['page']]) || ($_GET['page'] == 'home'))
{
    // Technically a header location should be a complete URL - http://...
    header("Location: home.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: register_globals is off so that's not an issue, the case insensitivity is just convenient for the later include. I know I can add more restrictive criteria (just a ctype_alnum() maybe) but that would just be redundant I guess? I'm arguing with a hoster which keeps saying some weird stuff gets executed due to my script, but I really can't reproduce any situation where malicious code could be injected.

Comment: I don't think it's that line letting things be injected

Answer (score 2):

Seems ok. Just add an exit() statement after header() to make sure that even if header() fails, your script terminates.

Answer (score 0):

this would be enough

```
 $allow = array('home', 'another_one', 'blah');
 $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'home';
 if(in_array($page, $allow, true))
     include "$page.php";
```

i'm not sure why you're using "header" there

Answer (score 0):

"good enough" is a very wide brush.  Can you expand a little?  Also, if you know $_GET['page'] should be restricted to a small set of values (say, integers, or identifiers containing only lowercase letters, et cetera) then it never hurts to validate the data with a regex.

Answer (score 0):

it might be better to do a regex on the $page firstly to ensure it meets the sanitised criteria of what can be passed in before checking further, if the contents of $page is not conforming, then do not process further...